# NoSQL vs NewSQL

Tags: database, comparison, nosql

I recently came upon the term **NewSQL**. It seems that it can be used with **SQL**, maintain **ACID** and still provide the **performance** and **scalability** of NoSQL. **This sounds great!**

I am wondering what are the pros and cons of NoSQL and NewSQL and why isn't NewSQL used more? Is it *only* because it is a new technology and it still lacks adoption and stable implementations?

Comment: https://www.voltdb.com/blog/2015/04/09/nosql-vs-newsql-choosing-right-tool/